# Impluse Response Function plots cut off in R Markdown PDF

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown

For some reason when using the irf() function and knitting the markdown to pdf the second of the two plots generated gets cut off. Is there a way to fix this or a way to call the individual plots one at a time to have them stack on top of each other instead?

[image of the cut off plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6nMx.png)

I have attempted to pass the which() argument to the plot() function but have not been successful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fig.width = 4` and `fig.height = 3` (use values that fit well your page) in your R code chunk or save the rendered plot in a separete folder, e.g. picture `pic.png` in `dir` folder and do this:

````
```{r, out.width="50%"}
knitr::include_graphics("dir/pic.png")
```
````

Note: This is not about the plot's dimensions but the dimensions used in knitting. All three chunk options can be set globally for the whole document. For more info see [these docs](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/).